# Argument error; wrong number of arguments given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to Ruby on Rails and been cracking my head on this. I have been following this tutorial here to make this form to save records into my DB - https://human-se.github.io/rails-demos-n-deets-2020/demo-resource-create/

This is my controller:

```
class ViewaddparamController < ActionController::Base
    def view_add_param
        newParam = ViewaddparamController.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html{ render :viewaddparam, locals: { newParam: newParam } }
        end
    end

    def add_param
        # new object from params
        mlParam = ViewaddparamController.new(params.require(:Viewaddparam_Controller).permit(:name, :machine_model, :parameter_1, :parameter_2, :parameter_3, :data_train_set, :start_date, :end_date))
        # respond_to block
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html do
                if mlParam.save
                    # success message
                    flash[:success] = "ML parameters saved successfully"
                    # redirect to index
                    redirect_to model_url
                else
                    # error message
                    flash.now[:error] = "Error: parameters could not be saved"
                    # render new
                    render :viewaddparam, locals: { newParam: newParam }
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My route:

```
  get 'viewparam', to: 'viewaddparam#view_add_param'
  post 'add_param', to: 'viewaddparam#add_param', as: 'add_param'
```

My view:

```
<%= form_with model: newParam, url: add_param_path, method: :post, local: true, scope: :Viewaddparam_Controller do |f| %>

...
```

I kept getting this error whenever I try to submit the form

```
ArgumentError in ViewaddparamController#add_param
Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

The error highlighted at my controller class, line 11.

What am I doing wrong here? I looked through the tutorial over and over but I can't see the fault here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mlParam = ViewaddparamController.new(params.require(:Viewaddparam_Controller)` it needs to be model i think but you are using controller which does not take any argument and you are passing one that is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you’re treating `ViewaddparamController` as both the controller – which in Rails terms is what responds to user requests - and the data model.

There’s often a one-to-one correlation to controllers and models, especially if you’re following what’s known as the RESTful pattern. So if your model was a `Product`, you might set it up in routes using a `resources` directive:

```rb
resources :products
```

That would set the app up to expect to use a `ProductsController`. And, using a similar coding style to your example, that would look a little like:

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    product = Product.new
    render :new, locals: { product: product }
  end

  def create
    product = Product.new(params.require(:product).permit(…))
    # etc
  end
  
  # etc
end
```

So you can see from this example that controller and model are related, but are named differently.

By using your controller name where you should be using the model, you’re calling `#new` on the controller, which is not normally something you need to do – controller instances are managed by the Rails app framework. And their initialiser doesn’t take any arguments, so Ruby complains that an initialiser that takes 0 arguments is being given 1.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the object creation is suppose to be the name of the model class. Wish the tutorial will have been clearer!